# Using Select and where statement in Criteria

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I am in the process of replacing jdbc with hibernate in my Web Application. I have learned that i don't have to write any SQL queries in this. Instead of this,criteria queries can help me.
These are my SQL queries which i want to convert to hibernate using criteria not HQL.

```
String getOrgIdQuery = "SELECT * FROM USER_DETAILS WHERE USER_ID= ?";
rsDeptName = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT DEPARTMENT_NAME FROM DEPARTMENT WHERE DEPARTMENT_ID ="+ DeptID + ";");
String insertCreateCdcValuesFirst = ("UPDATE User_Details SET User_Name=?, Organization_ID=?, Department_ID=?, Access_Ctrl = ?, User_Role=? WHERE User_ID = ?;");
```

Comment: It is not hard to do with `Criteria`.https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/tutorial.html

Comment: @AfsunKhammadli can u please tell me the query..?? I have gone through all these documents but still am not able to figure out this..!!

Comment: Ok I will add as answer

Comment: did you solve your problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First off all you must map your table with `POJOS`.

```
String getOrgIdQuery = "SELECT * FROM USER_DETAILS WHERE USER_ID= ?";
```

Preceding code in `Hibernate` look like following.

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(USER_DETAILS.class);
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("user_id",yourUserId));
List<USER_DETAILS> list = criteria.list();
```

Your second select query is also same as preceding.

```
String insertCreateCdcValuesFirst = ("UPDATE User_Details SET User_Name=?, Organization_ID=?, Department_ID=?, Access_Ctrl = ?, User_Role=? WHERE User_ID = ?;");
```

With `Hibernate Criteria` update looks like following:

```
USER_DETAILS user_details = (USER_DETAILES) session.get(USER_DETAILS.class,yourUserId);
user_details.setUser_Name(NewUserName);
user_details.setOrganization_Id(newOrganizationId);
// some other fields update goes here
session.update(user_details);
tx.commit();
```

I hope this help you.