# Update Blob column in Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, blob

I want to update Blob column in Hibernate. It insert successfully but when I use `saveorUpdate()` method for update my updated blob file it does nothing.

```
SessionFactory session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
Session s = session.openSession();
Transaction transaction = s.beginTransaction();
s.saveOrUpdate(image);
s.flush();
transaction.commit();
s.close();
```

Please resolve my problem or give me code for update blob in Hibernate or HQL or HCQL (any of them).

Comment: What is image? byte[] or class reference?

Comment: Did you map your entity and database table correctly? If yes please post your class structure

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30252798/using-select-and-where-statement-in-criteria/30254128#30254128 I think my answer will help you

Comment: are you have any code for update longblob in hibernate ?

Comment: There is no difference updating blob,longblob,String and etc. You can do update like my answer

Comment: yes sir its working thank you !!!